# Table marked as inavailable after rollbacking the UOW by db2

Tags: database, db2, etl

We tried to process the CSV file from Pentaho ETL tool but while we are processing new CSV file The DB2 table is going inaccessible state and getting below Error in ETL logs.

```
Could not insert SQL :
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1476, SQLSTATE=40506, SQLERRMC=-407, DRIVER=3.69.24


2023-08-30-02.53.08.702450+120 E709905392E671        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 29183                TID : 140232523507456 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE:                      NODE : 000            DB   : 
APPHDL  : 0-56243              APPID: 10.1.198.57.38305.230830005314
AUTHID  :                    HOSTNAME: 
EDUID   : 6442                 EDUNAME: db2agent  0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data management, sqldEndNoLogList, probe:1
MESSAGE : ADM5530W  The COMMIT processing of table "  "
          that used NOT LOGGED INITIALLY has been initiated.  It is recommended
          that you take a backup of this table's table space(s).

2023-08-30-02.53.10.218215+120 I709906064E598        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 29183                TID : 140231772727040 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE:                      NODE : 000            DB   : 
APPHDL  : 0-56247              APPID: 10.1.198.57.38310.230830005312
AUTHID  :                     HOSTNAME: 
EDUID   : 6440                 EDUNAME: db2agent  0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rollback_with_sqlcode, probe:100
MESSAGE : NLI or DMS force ROLLBACK
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 8 bytes
0x00007F8A1B29FDB8 : 2000 0000 0000 0000                         .......

 

2023-08-30-02.53.10.225134+120 I709906663E916        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 29183                TID : 140231772727040 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE:                     NODE : 000            DB   : 
APPHDL  : 0-56247              APPID: 10.1.198.57.38310.230830005312
AUTHID  :                    HOSTNAME: 
EDUID   : 6440                 EDUNAME: db2agent 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rollback_with_sqlcode, probe:220
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -407   sqlerrml: 35
sqlerrmc: TBSPACEID=37, TABLEID=1350, COLNO=2
sqlerrp : sqldFmt1
sqlerrd : (1) 0x8016001C      (2) 0x0000001C      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0xFFFFFB1F      (6) 0x00000000
sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
sqlstate:

 

2023-08-30-02.53.10.228076+120 E709907580E599        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 29183                TID : 140231772727040 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE:                      NODE : 000            DB   :
APPHDL  : 0-56247              APPID: 10.1.198.57.38310.230830005312
AUTHID  :                       HOSTNAME: 
EDUID   : 6440                 EDUNAME: db2agent  0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data management, sqldMarkObjInErr, probe:1
MESSAGE : ADM5571W  The "DATA" object with ID "1350" in table space "37" for
          table "   " is being marked as unavailable.
```

Note: I intentionally removed table names, etc in the DB logs

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The database is telling you that it rolled back the insert because at least one row being inserted was trying to put a NULL into a column defined as NOT NULL.  The rollback can take a "long" time if your commit-count is high and during this time the table may be inaccessible for some operations.  This is an error in YOUR  ETL logic, or in your CSV file, it should not attempt to insert NULL into NOT NULL columns, but should use some default value or other legitimate value for each not-null column. FIX your ETL code or csv file.

Comment: 1476 says transaction log is full.

Comment: SQL1476N  The current transaction was rolled back because of error
      "<sqlcode>".  SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column "<name>" is       not allowed.

Comment: Additionally, it is always a mistake to use NOT LOGGED INITIALLY on any persistent table (but fine to use it on a temporary table, or staging table), because in the event of an error (which you get because of broken ETL), you have to rebuild the table....

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you will have to drop and rebuild your target table.

This is the expected result, and the documented result, of using "NOT LOGGED INITIALLY" on a table that suffers a rollback in a transaction.

In your case, the insert transaction failed because the ETL was trying to put a NULL ino a column of the target-table that was defined as NOT NULL (giving sqlcode -407), causing the rollback (-1476) and because the target table had been placed into "not logged initially" mode (unlogged), the table was then placed into unavailable/inaccessible state following the rollback. This is the expected and documented behaviour.

You have to drop and recreate the your target table (no other action is possible).
If it was an important table with lots of other data, it will need to be restored from a backup.

You have to fix your ETL to verify that all target columns that are NOT NULL in the database have either a default value or a not-null value.

If you must use "NOT LOGGED INITIALLY" (it is fast and unlogged, but because it is unlogged the target table becomes unuseable after any error), so only use NLI (Not Logged Initially) on a temporary table or staging table, or if you've taken a copy of its contents prior to the NLI activation from which you can quickly restore.

Read more here:

SQL1476N
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql1250-sql1499#sql1476n

SQL0407N
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0250-sql0499#sql0407n